# how to make a GET request to return the information in a nested object, Mongoose Express

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, get, postman

I have been trying to make a get request that will return all of the objects in my nested object in My userSchema. when creating the route I grab the user by id and then I try to access the classwork property inside of it which is a nested object that contains an array of classwork objects that have their own properties. How can I make  GET request to show JSON for just the user's classwork?

Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ClassworkSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String,
    isDone: false
});

const OutcomesSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String, 
    isDone: false,
    isApproved: false
})

const MeetupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    location: String,
    attended: false
})
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    classwork: [ClassworkSchema],
    outcomes: [OutcomesSchema],
    meetups: [MeetupSchema],
  });



module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

GET request

```
  classworkRouter.get('/:userId/classwork', (req, res) => {
        User.findById(req.params.userId).populate('classwork').exec((err, data) => {
          if (err || !data) {
            res.status(404).json({error: 'user not found'});
          } else {
            res.json({data});
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Are you having difficulty in checking the response that you receive on get request using Postman?

Comment: if you want to only send selected data to the user you can use .select('fieldName') after populate

Comment: Post man is returning the whole user information, but I just want the array of classwork objects not all of the user information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can following this code

```
  classworkRouter.get('/:userId/classwork', (req, res) => {
        User.findById(req.params.userId).populate('classwork' ,'classwork').exec((err, data) => {
          if (err || !data) {
            res.status(404).json({error: 'user not found'});
          } else {
            res.json({data});
          }
        });
      });
```

please check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 0):

it would be work

```js
classworkRouter.get('/:userId/classwork', (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.params.userId).populate('classwork').exec((err, data) => {
    if (err || !data) {
      res.status(404).json({ error: 'user not found' });
    } else {
      res.json({ data: user.classwork });
    }
  });
});
```

and this is same code but little changed my style

```js
classworkRouter.get('/:userId/classwork', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId).populate('classwork')
    if (!user) throw
    return res.status(200).json({ data: user.classwork })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: 'user not found' });
  }
})
```